# How can I vertically center align text inside button?

Tags: css, button

I thought `line-height` would vertically center align text. But this is not happening for my button. Why?

The text is bottom aligned in FF, Opera and Safari.

[Her is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FFf8Y/2/).

```
<button class="get_discount_rate">Button</button>
```

```css
button {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #444;
  min-width: 90px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: or better yet, simply remove line-height property from the css rule

Comment: Yeah, Sheikh Heera just prooved it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vertically center aligned text inside `button` (Tested in Chrome, FF, Safari, Opera and IE8)

```css
button {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #444;
    min-width: 90px;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
}​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/FFf8Y/6/)